# Getting RateLimit but without a Header with retry-after value

Tags: dropbox-api

i am creating 2/file_requests/create using the Droobox java SDK.

When i am creating the request i get an rate limit. But with no info about a retry-after time.

When doing the same Request with HTTP REST Api
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/file_requests/create
{"title": "Homework submission","destination": "/File Requests/Homework","open": true}

i get a result of:
{
"error_summary": "rate_limit/..",
"error": {
".tag": "rate_limit"
}
}

Is the rate limit daily, weekly, monthly?
When does it reset?

Any hints are welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you're calling the [/2/file_requests/create](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-create) endpoint and are getting a `rate_limit` error. That's not a general API-level rate limiting response (which would have a `Retry-After`), but rather an endpoint-specific limit. It's documented as:

> `rate_limit` *Void* The user has reached the rate limit for creating file requests. The limit is currently 4000 file requests total.

That means that the connected account cannot create more file requests via the API. You'd need to reduce the file request count for that account to below 4000 in order to make more via the API.

The app can delete specific file requests using [/2/file_requests/delete](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-delete), or delete all closed file requests using [/2/file_requests/delete_all_closed](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-delete_all_closed). You can check the current number of file requests for the account using [/2/file_requests/count](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-count).

Comment: Do you mean i can have only 4000 File-Requests at all? I was creating a Request for all our customers so that they can send files this way.
In total we need around 10k of Request.

If the maximum is 4000 i have to rethink over the System i am building. Oups...

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for your help! Highly appreciated.
Hope i did set the status correctly. It´s the first question i asked at SO ;-)